# Split and Replace String using object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I would like to know is there any alternative any efficient method to split and replace string in javascript;

```
var str= "/go-where" or "/go"
var repl = "to"
var result = splitandreplace(str);

function splitandreplace(val, repl){
  var x= str.split("/")[1];
  var res= x.split("-")[0] + x.split('-')[1]!==undefined ? x.split('-')[1]=(en) :''; // will be to(en)
}

Expected Output:
when str is 
/go -> to
/go-where -> to(en)
```

Comment: not clear. Note that the valid `string` should be enclosed with single or double quotes

Comment: Maybe you want `val.replace('/go-where', 'to(en)').replace('/go', 'to')`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a regular expression:

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=fnb\" target=\"_blank\">#fnb</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=mobilesimcard\" target=\"_blank\">#mobilesimcard</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=what\" target=\"_blank\">#what</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=refugeechild\" target=\"_blank\">#refugeechild</a>";
var array = str.match(/#[a-z-_]+/ig)

console.log(array);
```